# Images are not being rendered in MarkdownTextBlock control in Windows universal application

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, markdown, windows-community-toolkit

I have below xaml code -

```
<Page
x:Class="MyProject1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Black">
<Grid Background="White" Name="mainGrid">

    <Border  BorderBrush="Cyan" BorderThickness="0.2" Margin="3,0,3,3">
        <ListView x:Name="ListView" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:MarkdownTextBlock Name="markdownBlock" Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe-UI">
                    </controls:MarkdownTextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

I am trying to display below markdown text on windows universal application (windows 10 app).

Here is the text in markdown-

**Sample Text** that is represented in markdown.    \n\n Please [click here](https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/teams/Pages/solutions.aspx) for more details. \n\n\n ![SQL2016]/(http://windowsitpro.com/site-files/windowsitpro.com/files/imagecache/large_img/uploads/2015/05/sql2016.jpg)/

In my windows universal application, below MarkdownTextBlock control renders only text and hyperlink but not the image :(

It is rendered as this -

[image]

However, the same markdown is rendered in browser fully -

[image]

I spent quite a lot of time on this.. but couldnt figure out the reason.. is this image rendering not possible with markdowntextblock? Not sure how the performance would be if I use webbrowser here..  What am I missing in my XAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's not your fault. The current version (1.3.1) of the UWP Community Toolkit doesn't support images for the `MarkdownTextBlock` at the moment.

But the guys are working on it as we can see:
https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/916
https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/pull/958

Even they are ready with this we are only waiting the version 1.4 release date which is April 5, 2017.

If you can't wait you can build the toolkit from source and use it in your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot @tóth-tibor for the information.  I see the code for rendering image is in this file  https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MarkdownTextBlock/Display/XamlRenderer.cs Could you please guide me how can I use this to render image in markdowntextblock in my win universal application ? I am not sure if I use this along with the text rendering and text wrapping property.

Comment: I you can't wait you need to get all these files from this [folder](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MarkdownTextBlock) and place them in a separate namespace. After that use this control like the originial one with the namespace fixes in the xaml. But don't forget to use the official one after relese.